# Strings vs constants for Redux action types

Tags: typescript, redux, flowtype

As suggested in [Redux guide](https://redux.js.org/recipes/reducing-boilerplate), the recommended approach is to define strings constants for Redux action types:

```
const FOO = 'FOO';
const BAR = 'BAR';

dispatch({ type: FOO });
```

To my understanding, most addressed concerns are applicable to untyped JavaScript, and constants are redundant with statically typed application:

```
type actionTypes = 'FOO' |
                   'BAR';

dispatch<actionTypes>({ type: 'FOO' });
dispatch<actionTypes>({ type: 'BAZ' }); // type error
```

Are there specific problems with not using constants like is shown above?

The question applies to both TypeScript and Flow, as they seem to be similar in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in [Redux source code](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/v3.7.2/src/createStore.js#L10-L12), the advantage of action type constants is that they can be namespaced:

```
export const ActionTypes = {
  INIT: '@@redux/INIT'
}
```

Same thing would require many changes in code that uses strings.

Answer (score 0):

Same as `PropTypes` are redundant in typescript, the action constants are redundant.

The reason for constants in redux actions is to avoid typos. You will get run-time error on a typo instead of silent reducer. With TypeScript, you don't need that

;-)